# How to remove \ from JSON

Tags: php, json

i have 1 text field which is Data..user would insert a JSON format data on the text field.  
Example of the data is : `{"user_id":"123"}` 
however when i receive the data. It would be `{\"user_id\”:\”123\”}` 
how to change the data into `{"user_id":"123"}` ??

Comment: I think you got `addslashes` on in PHP.http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: you upgrade your PHP to a less stone-age version that doesn't have magic_quotes turned on.